# Spark Scala DataFrame vs Dataset - Performance analysis

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Let's create a DataFrame and a Dataset with the same data:

```
val personDF = Seq(("Max", 33), ("Adam", 32), ("John", 62)).toDF("name", "age")

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val personDS = Seq(Person("Max", 33), Person("Adam", 32), Person("John", 62)).toDS()

personDF.select("name").explain  // DataFrame
// == Physical Plan ==
// LocalTableScan [name#14]

personDS.map(_.name).explain     // Dataset
// == Physical Plan ==
// *SerializeFromObject [staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, input[0, java.lang.String, true], true) AS value#29]
// +- *MapElements <function1>, obj#28: java.lang.String
//    +- *DeserializeToObject newInstance(class $line129.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Person), obj#27: $line129.$read$$iwC$$iwC$Person
//       +- LocalTableScan [name#2, age#3]
```

The Dataset Physical Plan incurs in additional `DeserializeToObject`, `MapElements`, and `SerializeFromObject` steps. **What are the performance implications of this?**

**EDIT:**

Are there any experiments/benchmarks available that compare:

- Execution speed
- Memory utilization
- Garbage Collection overhead

Comment: I found this one very helpful- https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html

Comment: this one also- https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.html

Comment: @squid thanks for the links! Do they mention performances at all?

Comment: @user8371915 I'm interested in actual benchmarks or other data. The short answer is "there is some overhead", I'd like to know "how much exactly". Tried to clarify in the question